# If $|f(0)|\geq r$, then $|f(z)|\geq (r-|z|)/(1-r|z|)$ for $|z|<r$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

The following is an exercise IX.1.5 in Gamelin

> Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic and satisfies $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|<1$. Show that if $|f(0)|\geq r$, then $|f(z)|\geq (r-|z|)/(1-r|z|)$ for $|z|<r$.

Let $\varphi:\Bbb D\to\Bbb D$ be a Blaschke factor $\varphi(z) = {f(0)-z\over 1-\overline{f(0)}z}$. Then applying Schwarz lemma on $\varphi\circ f$, we get
\begin{align*}
& |(\varphi\circ f)(z)|\leq |z|\Rightarrow \left|{f(0)-f(z)\over 1-\overline{f(0)}f(z)}\right|\leq |z|.\\
& |f(0)|-|f(z)|\leq |f(0)-f(z)|\leq |z||1-\overline{f(0)}f(z)|\leq |z|(1+|f(0)||f(z)|).\\
& r(1-|z||f(z)|)\leq |f(0)|(1-|z||f(z)|)\leq |z|+|f(z)|.\\
& {r-|z|\over 1+r|z|}\leq |f(z)|.
\end{align*}

This is as far as I get. I wonder if there's a way to get the stated inequality.

Comment: Assume $f(0) = r$, and apply the Schwarz Lemma, as you say, to, $\varphi\circ f$, but where $\varphi(z) = (z-r)/(1-rz)$.

Comment: @kandb Does it make any difference?

Comment: @kandb I think you want $(1 - \overline{r}z)$ in the denominator right? But we can I guess wlog just assume $f(0)$ is real after a rotation.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry. I was studying a different subject. I just checked your answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Schwarz inequality applied to $\varphi \circ f$ gives
$$
|z| \ge \left| \frac{f(0)-f(z)}{1-\overline{f(0)} f(z)}\right| 
$$
and, as you observed, applying the triangle inequality to the numerator and the denominator of the fraction on the right-hand side separately
$$
|z| \ge \left| \frac{f(0)-f(z)}{1-\overline{f(0)} f(z)}\right| 
\ge \frac{|f(0)|-|f(z)|}{1+ |f(0)|\cdot|f(z)|}
$$
is not good enough to get the desired estimate.

We need the following inequality (proof at the end):

> For complex numbers $a, b$ with $|a| < 1$ and $|b| < 1$ is
> $$ \tag{$*$}
>  \left| \frac{a-b}{1-\bar a b}\right| \ge \frac{||a|- |b||}{1-|a b|} \, .
> $$

Combining that with the Schwarz inequality we now get
$$
 |z| \ge \left| \frac{f(0)-f(z)}{1-\overline{f(0)} f(z)}\right| \ge \frac{|f(0)|-|f(z)|}{1- |f(0)|\cdot|f(z)|}
\ge \frac{r-|f(z)|}{1-r |f(z)|} \, ,
$$
so that
$$
(1-r |f(z)|) \cdot |z|\ge r-|f(z)| \, ,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
|f(z)| \ge \frac{r-|z|}{1-r|z|} \, .
$$

*Proof of the inequality $(*)$:* Using
$$
 |a-b|^2 = |a|^2 + |b|^2 - 2 \operatorname{Re}(\bar a b) \\
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
 1 - \left| \frac{a-b}{1-\bar a b}\right|^2 &= \frac{|1-\bar a b|^2-|a-b|^2}{|1-\bar a b|^2} \\
&= \frac{1 + |ab|^2 - (|a|^2+|b|^2)}{|1-\bar a b|^2} \\
&= \frac{(1-|a|^2)(1-|b|^2)}{|1-\bar a b|^2} \\
&\underset{(**)}{\le} \frac{(1-|a|^2)(1-|b|^2)}{(1-|ab|)^2} \\
&= 1- \left(\frac{|a|- |b|}{1-|a b|} \right)^2 \, .
\end{align}
$$
At $(**)$ we have applied the left triangle inequality $|1-\bar a b| \ge 1-|a b|$ to the denominators. It follows that
$$
\left| \frac{a-b}{1-\bar a b}\right|^2  \ge \left(\frac{|a|- |b|}{1-|a b|} \right)^2 
$$
and taking the square roots gives $(*)$.

*Remark:* Equality holds in $(*)$ if and only if equality holds at $(**)$, that is exactly if $\bar a b$ is real and non-negative.

Comment: how does $\varphi \circ f$ satisfy the Schwarz Lemma? It doesn‘t have a Zero at $0$, or at least I don‘t see it.

Comment: @MilesDefis: You are right, my original answer was wrong. – I have rewritten the answer completely, it should be correct now.